# VS2012 intellisense not working for custom controls

Tags: asp.net, intellisense, visual-studio-2012

Since installing VS2012 I have found that intellisense is failing to list any of my controls (registered in Web.config under the namespace "ctl") when I'm editing markup. Furthermore when I format the document, all instances of custom controls on the page are changed to lowercase.

I have tried:

- Clearing Temporary ASP.NET files
- Clearing ReflectedSchemas
- Resetting all Visual Studio settings

Comment: Is there any other component like Resharper installed or previously installed on the system? if yes VS imported settings from it. you cn reset it by Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Intellisense. check "Show Completion list after a character is typed" and the underlying checkboxes

Comment: All VS settings are completely reset. I don't have Resharper or similar installed. Also, I am referring to the HTML editor intellisense, not C#. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this issue is described by [this Microsoft Connect bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/758383/problems-with-intellisense-when-mixing-usercontrols-and-controls-in-the-same-tagprefix).

Comment: FYI - The dev is actively looking at this.

Answer (score 1):

This is confirmed fixed in Visual Studio 2012 Update 1 but I'd recommend downloading Update 2 since it's cumulative - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2797912